# Error when I try to edit user

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.4.18. I am getting this error when I try to edit user

```
Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\UsersController::edit()
```

Here is what I did

```
https://paste.laravel.io/Pyw5M#18
```

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: Also every time you inject the `User` model in that controller is unnecessary. You can just use `User::create([...])` or `User::find()` in those instances. If you're injecting the model instance it would be more the 'Laravel' way to use model binding instead.

Comment: @jfadich Thanks a lot. That helped. I am very grateful

Comment: Did that fix this error for you? If not could you share the route for `UsersController::edit()`

Comment: @jfadich That fixed the error

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
public function edit(User $user, $id)
{
    $user = $user->find($id);
    return view('admin/users/edit', compact('user'));
}
```

To this:

```
public function edit(User $user)
{
    return view('admin/users/edit', compact('user'));
}
```

When you define (User $user) laravel auto-injects the user model, so no need to find the model again based on the id.

In this case i expect your route to look like this:

```
Route::get('users/{user}/edit', UserController@edit)
```

Or you can use resource controllers so this is handled for you:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers